# Accessing UIWebView Information from another Class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsdata

*Hi everyone! to start off, my app involves web scraping and javascript injection authentication, since the site I'm trying to access data from, has no api (Don't worry it's legal). With that said here's my issue regarding a webView and its data:*

I currently have two classes, a **Main View**, and a **Login View**. When the app is launched, it will look for a stored username, if it finds one it loads up the main view, if it does not it slides up a modal view controller (loginView).

What the loginView allows me to do is authenticate the user, in order to display the page from where I want to scrape data. Once authentication is complete, and the page I need is loaded (hidden) the loginView slides out of sight. What I'm trying to do next us have the mainView scrape the loaded site. I know how to scrape the data, but my problem is communicating that data from the loginView (currentURL) to my mainView, which will handle the scraping.

I also want to have a logout button in the mainView so that when it is pressed, it sends a request to load the logout url in the webview to logout the user.

*To summarize the issue, how would I basically communicate data between my mainViewController and my loginViewController's webView information?*

Help would be appreciated! Thank you so much!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use either composition or notification design pattern:

**Composition:** It allows for multiple objects to work together to build a greater system. Composition, the technique of creating objects that have references to other objects, is a fundamental concept of OOP

here a intro on how to implement [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710411/ios-grasping-composition)

**Notification:** provides a mechanism for broadcasting information within a program. It is a singleton object that allows for objects to be notified of events occurring. It allows you to satisfy the goal of communicating between a controller and an arbitrary object.

apple doc [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-CEGCCFID)