# How to call method of other class?

Tags: ios, iphone, methods, delegates

I am working on feedback kind of iPhone app. Where I am getting stuck for getting values from other class. Suppose I have three view controller classes "Class-A", "Class-B" and "Class-C". And I have created delegate for class B and C.

Initially my root is Class-A. So from Class-A, I am presenting Class-B and by using class B.delegate = self, I am calling Class-B delegate method in Class-A. And also there is no connection between Class-B and Class-C. So is it possible that if I will come from Class-C to Class-A then same Class-B delegate method will invoke again?

A method that I want to invoke in Class-A is -

```
-(void)saveAllVisitOptions:(SignIn *)signIn
{
    Store *store1 = [[Store alloc] init];
    store1.signINN  =[[SignIn alloc] init];
    store1.signINN = signIn;
    [resultArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexValue withObject:store1];

    [Util setArrayPreference:resultArray forKey:@"Store"];
}
```

So if I will use singleton for this above method so will it work properly?
I have searched all over but unable to find solution for that.

Comment: Did you try notifications?

Comment: @KonstantinThanks for answer but i didn't use notification. How it will work here ?

Comment: Best design pattern to use is Composition, It allows for multiple objects to work together to build a greater system and is a fundamental concept of OOP. Take a looks at this example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710411/ios-grasping-composition)

Comment: maybe this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c?rq=1) will help you )

Comment: @KonstantinBut how class-C delegate method will invoke in Class-A ? how can i pass reference of Class-C ?

Comment: just post your notification!

Comment: @KonstantinSorry, i am not using notification concept.

Comment: then better try singleton...it's simple to use)

Comment: @KonstantinOk, pls check my updated question and let me know for this case.

Comment: @AnandGautam try to make singleton for Class-C.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define some mechanism to know that the control is going from Class-C to Class-A, either using a shared instance of a class or saving an entry in NSUserDefaults, then trigger the delegate method from Class-A.

**Singleton** (singleton.h) 
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL isReturningFromClassC;

in **Class-C**, set 
    [singletonInstance setIsReturningFromClassC:YES];

in **Class-A** 
    if([singletonInstance setIsReturningFromClassC])
        // Call delegate

- singletonInstance is the shared-instance of the sinlegton

Comment: @RaviWhat you mean by mechanism? I have tried by using singleton.

Comment: Then define a variable and set it on/off as required. Like you can set it on in the Class-C at the last movement in the process of going to Class-A, and in Class-A check whether the variable is on. And call the delegate if the variable is on.

Comment: @RaviSisodia I'm not sure I understand what you mean ever. Please share some code to explain your answer.

Comment: Anand Gautam: Using singleton class is the same thing what I told you is 'shared instance'.

Comment: Still don't understand what you are talking about. Why do you need to set a boolean flag.

Comment: So, that you can determine that the control, that is coming to Class-A, is coming from Class-C; not from any other Class. As you stated - "if I will come from Class-C to Class-A then same Class-B delegate method will invoke again"

Comment: "As you stated"? I'm not the person asking the question. This can be done with out using a boolean flag. Seems like a lot of effort for something so simple.

Comment: Hey Popeye. I'm answering it in the context as he asked. He used Singleton, I answered it at his level. If he knows NSUserDefaults, that will be a better way, and Some answered for NSNotifications, I think, that will be the best way. And Sorry, I thought you asked the question. Just Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like

```
- (void)someMethodYouCallInClassA
{
    // Simple and some may call none efficient way.
    // Personally not sure why some call it none efficient.
    ClassB *myClassB = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    [myClassB someMethodYouCallInClassB];
}
```

Or you could use a singleton which is what many would say to use. To do this

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *userData;

+ (ClassA *)sharedInstance;
- (void)myMethodInClassA
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
#import ClassA.h

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize userData = _userData;

static ClassA *classASharedInstance = nil;

+ (ClassA *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t instanceToken;
    dispatch_once(&instanceToken, ^{
         classASharedInstance = [[ClassA alloc] init];
    });
    return classASharedInstance;
}

- (void)myMethodInClassA
{ 
     // Do what it is want
}

@end
```

Then in you classB you can just do

```
 - (void)method....
 {
     ClassA *myClassA = [ClassA sharedInstance]; // If the instance has already been set then no need to do this again.
     [myClassA myMethodInClassA];
 }
```

This will allow you to easily access `classA`s methods and properties. I have included `userData` as an example of sharing properties. If you set `userData` in one class you will be able to access that instance of `userData` in another class easily.

If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: @PopeyeThanks for giving me time.Can u pls check my updated question ?

Comment: Yes a singleton would work where you want it. Using the same way I have done this in my answer you should be able to implement this easy enough. If you want anything else please just ask.